# Insert from text box using OLEDB

Tags: c#, insert, oracle10g, oledbcommand

I'm getting an error while I'm trying to insert a value from a C# form using `OLEDB Connection`.

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO test_table (username,password) " +
"VALUES (@user,@pass)";

objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, objConnection);
objCmd.Parameters.Add("@user", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value =TextBox1.Text.Trim();

objCmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value= TextBox2.Text.Trim();

// execute the command
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

objConnection.Close();
Label1.Text = "Command run";
```

Error is

> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: One or more
>   errors occurred during processing of command. ORA-00936: missing
>   expression

Comment: Can anyone help me to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're missing a space between `VALUES` friend. I added one after the `)` in the fields list for you in the below example.

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO test_table (username,password) " +
"VALUES (@user,@pass)";
```

Comment: @JojoGeorge, it's not giving the error? Is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up Parameters like this :-

```
objConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConnection);
objConnection.ConnectionString = strConnection;

objConnection.Open();



// set the SQL string
strSQL = "INSERT INTO test_table (username,password) " +
"VALUES (@user,@pass)";
// Create the Command and set its properties
objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, objConnection);

objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", TextBox1.Text);

objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextBox2.Text);

// execute the command
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

objConnection.Close();
```

Comment: I usually use nvarchar that is the unicode type. VarChar is dependent on teh windows code page used.

Comment: I would also reccommend using Data Adapters.

Comment: Hi,Derek .Thanks for Your Help. Where did you edit the code actually? sos that i could try using that code. I'm still not getting results.shows the same error!

Comment: check the Parameters, there setup differently. I've avoided the OLEDBType, I use Data Adapters, you should look into using those, i think they are way better.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

strSQL = "INSERT INTO test_table (username,password) " +
"VALUES (?,?)";

using OleDb you need to put "?" rather than @param for parameter